# Is it possible to merge or use multiple code analysis dictionary files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, code-analysis

I have a Code Analysis Dictionary file that I use throughout all my projects, so naturally I have it reside in a shared directory and add it to my project as a link. But, I ran into a situation where one of my projects (and **only** one) needs additional recognized words, so I added an additional Code Analysis Dictionary file specific to the project, but it doesn't seem to get recognized. If I remove the common file that is linked in then the specific project file works.

I'm wondering if there is any way to utilize more than one file for a project somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I do routinely without any problems.  Are you sure the build action is correct on each of the two files?  If so, do the changes work if they're all in the same file?  (Some kinds of dictionary content cannot be overridden, which could explain why one file's contents only seem to be applied in the absence of the other file.)

Comment: Yes. Both have their properties set to CodeAnalysisDictionary and merging both files into one manually fixes the issues. I'm not sure how you got 2 different files to work in conjunction. Could you possibly create a solution and upload it for me to look at?